# > Task :@react-native-firebase_messaging:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-firebase

When I try to make android build using these commands `yarn run android` OR `react-native run-android` then I have shown this error. Please help mw solve this error.

here's package.json

```
  "@react-native-firebase/admob": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.5.0",
```

error:

```
> Configure project :react-native-firebase_messaging
:react-native-firebase_messaging package.json found at /Users/apple/Desktop/xnd-react-native/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/package.json
:@react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /Users/apple/Desktop/xnd-react-native/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_messaging:firebase.bom using default value: 26.8.0
:react-native-firebase_messaging package.json found at /Users/apple/Desktop/xnd-react-native/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging/package.json
:react-native-firebase_messaging:version set from package.json: 11.5.0 (11,5,0 - 11005000)
:react-native-firebase_messaging:android.compileSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-firebase_messaging:android.targetSdk using custom value: 31
:react-native-firebase_messaging:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_messaging:reactNativeAndroidDir /Users/apple/Desktop/xnd-react-native/node_modules/react-native/android

> Task :@react-native-firebase_messaging:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
17 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 16 up-to-date
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue since last month....has anybody found any solution to this??

Comment: @Sjonchhe I have found the solution. you just update the jdk version and try it(recommend jdk 11)

Comment: @vjtechno Can you tell how you updated the jdk version? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I also have the same issue in jdk 8. When I change the jdk 8 to 11, it work for me.

To update from jdk 8 to 11 check https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1988#issuecomment-1070831039

Comment: how can you change the jdk from 8 to 11?

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Update the JDK version and try it,

you can update JDK using this command

```
choco install -y nodejs-lts openjdk11
```

Answer (score -2):

When I switched from JDK 8 to 11, it solved it.

Following the instruction to switch

1. Open a new Terminal window and input:

   ```
   /usr/libexec/java_home -V
   ```
2. It might look like this:

   ```
   Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):

   11.0.17 (arm64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 11.0.17" 
   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk- 
   11.0.17.jdk/Contents/Home

   1.8.0_292 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 8" 
   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk- 
   8.jdk/Contents/Home
   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk- 
   11.0.17.jdk/Contents/Home
   ```

You might see only one which might be 1.8(JDK 8), if so then go to https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/ to download JDK 11.

3. After a successful download and installation. you will run this command to switch.

   ```
    export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
   ```
4. Check your JDK version in a Terminal:

   ```
    java --version
   ```

You can also check out this link below

https://medium.com/@devkosal/switching-java-jdk-versions-on-macos-80bc868e686a

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information.

Comment: I  have provided the essential part of the answer, or am I not doing the correct thing?