# firebase cloud messaging issue in Android for react native project

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add firebase messaging in react native project.
But getting below error when i try to run the project into Android.

Do i have to do any external setting or add firebase messaging into gradle file or does it automatically get added.

```html
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.5.0",
 "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^16.5.0",
 "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.5.0",
```

but error is :

> Task :react-native-firebase_messaging:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

any help.

Comment: This looks similar to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70167109/4044241 could you check if the same applies here?

Comment: JDK11 works for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [> Task :@react-native-firebase\_messaging:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69862012/task-react-native-firebase-messagingcompiledebugjavawithjavac-failed)